# I Have Select One Video and Audio file and now I Want To add My Selected Audio/Sound in to My Video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp4parser, mediamuxer

**I Have Select One Video and Audio file and now I Want To add My Selected Audio in to Video**

And I Want to Save The output file in .mp4 in external or internal Storage directory
I search on Google and Found that ffmpeg,mediaMuxer,mp4parser but i can not get proper example or solution.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem and now **it is solved completely.**
here is the solution:[Merging video and audio with MediaMuxer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572067/android-how-to-mux-audio-file-and-video-file)

Comment: Thank You Bro i Will Try