# android - How to mux audio file and video file?

Tags: android, video, mediamuxer

i have a 3gp file that is recorded from the microphone and a mp4 video file.
i want to mux audio file and video file in to a mp4 file and save it.
i searched a lot but didn't find any thing helpful for using MediaMuxer api of android.
[MediaMuxer api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html)

UPDATE : this is my method that mux two files , i have an Exception in it.
and the reason is that the destination mp4 file doesn't have any track!
can someOne help me with adding audio and video track to muxer??

Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to stop the muxer
```

my code:

```
private void cloneMediaUsingMuxer( String dstMediaPath) throws IOException {
    // Set up MediaExtractor to read from the source.
    MediaExtractor soundExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    soundExtractor.setDataSource(audioFilePath);
    MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd2 = getAssets().openFd("Produce.MP4");
    videoExtractor.setDataSource(afd2.getFileDescriptor() , afd2.getStartOffset(),afd2.getLength());


    //PATH
    //extractor.setDataSource();
    int trackCount = soundExtractor.getTrackCount();
    int trackCount2 = soundExtractor.getTrackCount();

    //assertEquals("wrong number of tracks", expectedTrackCount, trackCount);
    // Set up MediaMuxer for the destination.
    MediaMuxer muxer;
    muxer = new MediaMuxer(dstMediaPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
    // Set up the tracks.
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(trackCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < trackCount; i++) {
        soundExtractor.selectTrack(i);
        MediaFormat SoundFormat = soundExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
        int dstIndex = muxer.addTrack(SoundFormat);
        indexMap.put(i, dstIndex);
    }

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> indexMap2 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(trackCount2);
    for (int i = 0; i < trackCount2; i++) {
        videoExtractor.selectTrack(i);
        MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
        int dstIndex2 = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);
        indexMap.put(i, dstIndex2);
    }


    // Copy the samples from MediaExtractor to MediaMuxer.
    boolean sawEOS = false;
    int bufferSize = MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE;
    int frameCount = 0;
    int offset = 100;
    ByteBuffer dstBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo2 = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

    muxer.start();
    while (!sawEOS) {
        bufferInfo.offset = offset;
        bufferInfo.size = soundExtractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, offset);
        bufferInfo2.offset = offset;
        bufferInfo2.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, offset);

        if (bufferInfo.size < 0) {
            sawEOS = true;
            bufferInfo.size = 0;
            bufferInfo2.size = 0;
        }else if(bufferInfo2.size < 0){
            sawEOS = true;
            bufferInfo.size = 0;
            bufferInfo2.size = 0;
        }
        else {
            bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = soundExtractor.getSampleTime();
            bufferInfo2.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
            //bufferInfo.flags = extractor.getSampleFlags();
            int trackIndex = soundExtractor.getSampleTrackIndex();
            int trackIndex2 = videoExtractor.getSampleTrackIndex();
            muxer.writeSampleData(indexMap.get(trackIndex), dstBuf,
                    bufferInfo);

            soundExtractor.advance();
            videoExtractor.advance();
            frameCount++;

        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"f:"+frameCount,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    muxer.stop();
    muxer.release();

}
```

**UPDATE 2: problem solved! check my answer to my question.**

thanks for your help

Comment: Are you willing to use the NDK or do you want to solution to be in pure java?

Comment: Any thing that solve the problem is perfect.pure java and mediaMuxer is better i think.

Comment: Can you provide more of the exception detail? There should be an exception code from MediaMuxer provided in logcat in you look at the verbose settings

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had some problem with tracks of audio and video files.
they gone and every thing is ok with my code , but Now you can use it for **merging an audio file and a video file together**.

Code:

```
private void muxing() {

String outputFile = "";

try {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "final2.mp4");
    file.createNewFile();
    outputFile = file.getAbsolutePath();

    MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    AssetFileDescriptor afdd = getAssets().openFd("Produce.MP4");
    videoExtractor.setDataSource(afdd.getFileDescriptor() ,afdd.getStartOffset(),afdd.getLength());

    MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    audioExtractor.setDataSource(audioFilePath);

    Log.d(TAG, "Video Extractor Track Count " + videoExtractor.getTrackCount() );
    Log.d(TAG, "Audio Extractor Track Count " + audioExtractor.getTrackCount() );

    MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

    videoExtractor.selectTrack(0);
    MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
    int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);

    audioExtractor.selectTrack(0);
    MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
    int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);

    Log.d(TAG, "Video Format " + videoFormat.toString() );
    Log.d(TAG, "Audio Format " + audioFormat.toString() );

    boolean sawEOS = false;
    int frameCount = 0;
    int offset = 100;
    int sampleSize = 256 * 1024;
    ByteBuffer videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
    ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();


    videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
    audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);

    muxer.start();

    while (!sawEOS)
    {
        videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
        videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);


        if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
            sawEOS = true;
            videoBufferInfo.size = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
            videoBufferInfo.flags = videoExtractor.getSampleFlags();
            muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);
            videoExtractor.advance();


            frameCount++;
            Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
            Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "frame:" + frameCount , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    boolean sawEOS2 = false;
    int frameCount2 =0;
    while (!sawEOS2)
    {
        frameCount2++;

        audioBufferInfo.offset = offset;
        audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);

        if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
            sawEOS2 = true;
            audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime();
            audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.getSampleFlags();
            muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, audioBufferInfo);
            audioExtractor.advance();


            Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
            Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "frame:" + frameCount2 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    muxer.stop();
    muxer.release();


} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 1 " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 2 " + e.getMessage());
}
```

}

thanks to these sample codes:[MediaMuxer Sample Codes-really perfect](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeAndMuxTest)

Comment: I copy your code, but it doesn't work , Error: Failed to add the track to the muxer? How to resolve it? Thx.

Comment: Great example. To add something extra: 
I encountered a problem when trying to mux in an audio track that was not from a supported format. Basically if you are producing an mp4 video from the encoded video and audio tracks, these have to be from a range of specific mime-types (formats). In the case of audio, these MUST be MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AMR_NB, MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AMR_WB or MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC. 
Else you will encounter "Unknown mime type 'audio/whatever'." error.

Comment: Hello @mohamad ali gharat how to add sdcard video and audio without use Asset folder?

Comment: @AnandDiamond use this library to choose the file: https://github.com/bartwell/ExFilePicker, this library gives you the path of selected file, get that path and put it in videoExtractor.setDataSource(); this can get path as parameter. I'm 90% sure this will work

Comment: But In this my case first i have capture video and second case view this video and bottom up get sd card mp3 after click mp3 this time merge both any soultion?

Comment: @AnandDiamond the only thing that you want is path of video or audio file. If you have the path then you can do it

Comment: @mohamadaligharat i can do it mp4 file is created but i can't play this file error

Comment: @AnandDiamond Can you play it with MXPlayer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146417/discussion-between-anand-diamond-and-mohamad-ali-gharat).

Comment: @mohamadaligharat I am getting Unsupported mime 'audio/raw' error when I am trying to run the .above code. I am recording audio separately but I am not able to understand how to  convert audio to a particular encoded format. so that the above code can work. Please help if you can.

Comment: @mohamadaligharat: The resulting MP4 file seems to be compressed and pixelated.  Is there any way to get a high-resolution MP4 output?

Comment: what happens if the length of the audio is shorter than length of the video? the audio will stop when the video is still playing

Comment: @mohamadaligharat  Where did you get the code for this? Is it possible to know if the output file might be bad? In some cases, I got a black video (with audio that plays fine)... And when I choose "mp3" file as audio input file, it still has the error of `IllegalStateException: Failed to add the track to the muxer` ...

Comment: @SuppressWarnings How to know which ones are supported ? How to check it before trying to mux ?

Comment: @AnswerZhao, did you get the answer?

Comment: @mohamadaligharat, i muxed a .mp4 video file having two tracks, video and .aac,when i merge this with another .aac file, i get a video without internal audio track of video file. any clue??

Comment: @androiddeveloper i got error "E/MPEG4Writer: Unsupported mime 'audio/mpeg' with mp4 video and mp3 audio file muxing. any solution?

Comment: code prefect work but when i mix video ans audio change video width and height. Please provide any answer

Comment: @mohamadaligharat I am getting this exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to stop the muxer ) on videos which I have downloaded, but on videos created from camera is working fine. Please tell me what should be the possible solution? Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of the first line of code: `File file = ______`. Aren't we initializing our audio and video extractors in the next two pieces of code? Thanks.

Comment: In case any facing java.lang.IllegalStateException while muxing, increase the sampleSize.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks mohamad ali gharat for this answer, it's help me too much.
But there is some change I made to code to work,
first: I change

> `videoExtractor.setDataSource` to
>   `videoExtractor.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
>   + "/Produce.MP4");`

to load video from `SDCard`.
Second: I get error with

> `videoBufferInfo.flags = videoExtractor.getSampleFlags();`

so change it to

> `videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME;`

to make it work as this link say [Android MediaMuxer failed to stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750790/android-mediamuxer-failed-to-stop)

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need to get working in ffmpeg. Here's a link to help with that:

[FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

ffmpeg requires the NDK on Android.

Once you have that working, you can work on muxing the audio and video together using ffmpeg. Here's a link to a question that does it with 2 video files (the answer should be similar).

[FFMPEG mux video and audio (from another video) - mapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938581/ffmpeg-mux-video-and-audio-from-another-video-mapping-issue)

Comment: thanks for that. I found a source code that was near to what and easier than ffmpeg.but i don't have any experience even in MediaMuxer class and it's behavior , can you help me with a easy to use answer??

Answer (score 1):

```
private const val MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE = 256 * 1024

fun muxAudioVideo(destination: File, audioSource: File, videoSource: File): Boolean {

    var result : Boolean
    var muxer : MediaMuxer? = null

    try {

        // Set up MediaMuxer for the destination.

        muxer = MediaMuxer(destination.path, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)

        // Copy the samples from MediaExtractor to MediaMuxer.

        var videoFormat : MediaFormat? = null
        var audioFormat : MediaFormat? = null
    
        var muxerStarted : Boolean = false

        var videoTrackIndex = -1
        var audioTrackIndex = -1

        // extractorVideo

        var extractorVideo = MediaExtractor()

        extractorVideo.setDataSource(videoSource.path)

        val tracks = extractorVideo.trackCount

        for (i in 0 until tracks) {

            val mf = extractorVideo.getTrackFormat(i)

            val mime = mf.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME)
    
            if (mime!!.startsWith("video/")) {

                extractorVideo.selectTrack(i)
                videoFormat = extractorVideo.getTrackFormat(i)

                break
            }
        }


        // extractorAudio

        var extractorAudio = MediaExtractor()

        extractorAudio.setDataSource(audioSource.path)

        for (i in 0 until tracks) {

            val mf = extractorAudio.getTrackFormat(i)

            val mime = mf.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME)

            if (mime!!.startsWith("audio/")) {

                extractorAudio.selectTrack(i)
                audioFormat = extractorAudio.getTrackFormat(i)

                break

            }

        }

        val audioTracks = extractorAudio.trackCount

        // videoTrackIndex

        if (videoTrackIndex == -1) {

            videoTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat!!)

        }

        // audioTrackIndex

        if (audioTrackIndex == -1) {

            audioTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat!!)

        }

        var sawEOS = false
        var sawAudioEOS = false
        val bufferSize = MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE
        val dstBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize)
        val offset = 0
        val bufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()

        // start muxer
    
        if (!muxerStarted) {

            muxer.start()

            muxerStarted = true

        }

        // write video
    
        while (!sawEOS) {

            bufferInfo.offset = offset
            bufferInfo.size = extractorVideo.readSampleData(dstBuf, offset)

            if (bufferInfo.size < 0) {
    
                sawEOS = true
                bufferInfo.size = 0

            } else {

                bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = extractorVideo.sampleTime
                bufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME
                muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, dstBuf, bufferInfo)
                extractorVideo.advance()

            }

        }

        // write audio
    
        val audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize)

        while (!sawAudioEOS) {

            bufferInfo.offset = offset
            bufferInfo.size = extractorAudio.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset)

            if (bufferInfo.size < 0) {
    
                sawAudioEOS = true
                bufferInfo.size = 0

            } else {

                bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = extractorAudio.sampleTime
                bufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME
                muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrackIndex, audioBuf, bufferInfo)
                extractorAudio.advance()

            }

        }

        extractorVideo.release()
        extractorAudio.release()

        result = true

    } catch (e: IOException) {

        result = false

    } finally {

        if (muxer != null) {
            muxer.stop()
            muxer.release()
        }

    }

    return result

}
```