# Android Audio video encoder using MediaCodec API

Tags: android, audio, video, encode, android-mediacodec

I am developing an App that need audio-video encoding simultaneously. I checked the Google Grafika https://github.com/google/grafika CameraCaptureActivity, but it only encodes the video data. How can I encode audio data with other MediaCodec object and create a mp4 with MediaMuxer that contains both audio and video.

Comment: it would be helpful if you stated which API you're targeting and the type of audio data you wish to mux. prior to API18 the built-in muxer isn't supported and you have to use a 3rd party tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android - How to mux audio file and video file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572067/android-how-to-mux-audio-file-and-video-file)