# How to add music file to a video file in android programmatically

Tags: android, mediamuxer

I have a video file in mp4-Format(H264) and a AAC-File. I want to add the sound file to this video file with android studio. I have found out that i have to use MediaMuxer but I could not manage to code it :(.

Comment: There is a question  about MediaMuxer, maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572067/android-how-to-mux-audio-file-and-video-file

Comment: Thank you very much sir. With the link i could find my mistake